# Intercept hyperlink click with Delphi TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi

Using Delphi 7, with a TWebBrowser component with a HTML file loaded... How does one intercept a hyperlink click so that I can decide whether to do something other than allow the TWebBrowser to fetch the link?

I have tried the following, but the event is never triggered when I click on a hyperlink:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(Sender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; var URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  Cancel := True;
  ShowMessage(URL);
  WebBrowser1.Stop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

We do almost the exact code you show above.

Did you hook up your event handler in the component?

We don't do the .Stop. I'm not sure what that does or why you'd need to do it.  The Cancel := TRUE should is sufficient for what we do here.

Comment: Yes, I hooked up the event handler for BeforeNavigate2.

Comment: I found the culprit.  The Skin library I am using (AlphaSkins) is preventing the event from triggering.  If I disable the skin manager, the BeforeNavigate2 event fires.  When I enable the skin manager, the event never triggers.